# How printf works in scala?

Tags: scala, formatting

I am learning Scala and spark and wanted to print some formatted logs.

Here is what i got some examples:

```
val flag : Boolean = true 
val charA : Char = 'a' 
val piVal : Float = 3.14159265f
val num : Int = 1 

println(f"val of pi = $piVal%.3f")

println(f"another formatting : $num%05d")

println(s"values like $num $flag $charA")

println(s"evaluate expression = ${1+2}")
```

But i did not understand the meaning of all these.

Please suggest when to use f and when to use s with printf and what is the format of using this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation about this can be found in [String Interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html):

- `s` is used when using the variables directly in the string

```
println(s"values like $num $flag $charA")
```

- `f` is used when you want to adjust the formatting in the string, similar to printf in other languages, such as printing it with 3 decimal places from your example:

```
println(f"val of pi = $piVal%.3f")
```